# Resuming to the main activity

Tags: android

I am currently developing an Android 2.2 application that needs to resume to the main activity from another one.

I am using this code:

```
private void btnAbort_OnClick(View v) 
    {
        startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), Main.class));
        finish();
    }
```

but when I call the method (by clicking a button) I get the following error:

02-02 20:05:19.117: E/dalvikvm(864): Unable to open stack trace file '/data/anr/traces.txt': Permission denied

What is going wrong here?

Edit:
Manifest code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="eu.game"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name=".SingleplayerActivity"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="eu.game.SINGLEPLAYERACTIVITY" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Please, put here code of your AndroidManifest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the problem by creating a new thread for the second activity. Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

If you're *resuming* to the main activity and not just starting it, there's no reason to call startActivity.  Just finish the current Activity, and Android will pop it off the Activity Stack and go to the previous one.  For more information, you can read up on the [Android Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) in the docs.

Comment: I've tried to just use finish(), but I am getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Trying passing this instead of v.getContext().

Is there any long running operation launched by your code ?

Comment: I've also tried this. I get the same error. My app is pretty much a blank one, with just a few buttons on both activity-layouts, but no functionality aside from switching between the two activities when a button is clicked.

Comment: Could you make you call to finish more explicit : YourActivityClass.this.finish()